# Where can I download previous versions of twisted?

Tags: python-3.x, twisted

Where can I download previous versions of twisted?

I can download the latest version here  https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted

but sometimes the latested version  is not compatible,where can I find the previous versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) has old versions:
example:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Twisted/12.0.0

Running `pip install Twisted==` in the terminal results in this:

```
Collecting Twisted==
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Twisted== (from 
versions: 2.1.0, 9.0.0, 10.0.0, 10.1.0, 10.2.0, 11.0.0, 11.1.0, 12.0.0, 12.1.0, 12.2.0, 12.3.0, 13.0.0, 13.1.0, 13.2.0, 14.0.0, 14.0.1, 14.0.2, 15.0.0, 15.1.0, 15.2.0, 15.2.1, 15.3.0, 15.4.0, 15.5.0, 16.0.0, 16.1.0, 6.1.1, 16.2.0, 16.3.0, 16.3.1, 16.3.2, 16.4.0, 16.4.1, 16.5.0rc1, 16.5.0rc2, 16.5.0, 16.6.0rc1, 16.6.0, 16.7.0rc1, 16.7.0rc2, 17.1.0rc1, 17.1.0, 17.5.0, 17.9.0rc1, 17.9.0)
No matching distribution found for Twisted==
```

which seams to show a list of version, hope this helps

Comment: Is there a list of previous versions?